# how to create a magento like $this to access its assigned class methods and properties?

Tags: php, magento, this

In Magento 1.5 i see that its used $this->getChildHtml(), how so?
I now that we cannot reassign $this in PHP. I would like to define methods that could be accessed with $this through out my project just as Magento does.

Comment: Perhaps best to start by learning the basics of PHP, especially [classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). This is new in PHP5, in case you've only written procedural PHP4 till now.

Comment: The only way you can access `$this` is to extend the class yourself. `$this` really represents the instance of the class you method is working with.

Answer (score 4):

The phtml files in Magento are able to use this because they're rendered by a block's `_toHtml` method

```
//simplified version
protected function _toHtml()
{
    include('path/to/template.phtml')
}

protected _someMethod()
{
    return 'some thing';
}
```

and then in the template

```
#File: path/to/template.phtml
<h1><?php $this->_someMethod(); ?></h1>
```

If you want to define your own methods, you'll need to define your own block classes, and use those block classes to add phtml templates to the layout. Both topics are bigger that a single stack overflow answer.